# ELSE/IF Statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript, validation, extjs, if-statement, playframework

I cannot get the below IF statement to work properly. The first two statements are executing perfectly. However, the last statement (the one with != statement) is not being read at all. I do not know where I am going wrong.

```
    function validatePrivate(v){
    if (cbSwitchStatus.getValue()!='P') {
        if (v=='') return true;
        else return 'This valid is not valid.';
    }
    else {
        if (storePrivate.findExact('disp',v) > -1) return true;
        else return 'This value is not valid.';
    }
    else{
        if(cbServCarrier.getValue() != cbPrivateCarrier.getValue()) return true;
        else return 'This value is not valid.';
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you imagine any case for the second `else` that had not already been handled with the first `else`? There is no `if else else`

Comment: Why don't you try using proper {} everywhere. I think that would solve the problem.

Comment: grab a book about programming.Start right from the  very basic..

Comment: As a **minor technical beef** I find that functions/methods that return multiple data types to be awkward to deal with. Have you considered returning an object that has 2 properties. 1.) a boolean (true|false) "valid" flag, and 2.) a string containing the error message (if there was an error)?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you cannot have multiple else's because the last else will simply never be evaluated...

```
 function validatePrivate(v){
    if (cbSwitchStatus.getValue()!='P') {
        if (v=='') return true;
        return 'This valid is not valid.';
    }
    else if (storePrivate.findExact('disp',v) > -1) {
        return 'This value is not valid.';
    }
    else if(cbServCarrier.getValue() != cbPrivateCarrier.getValue()) {
        return 'This value is not valid.';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (
     cbSwitchStatus.getValue()!='P' && v=='' ||
     storePrivate.findExact('disp',v) > -1 ||
     cbServCarrier.getValue() != cbPrivateCarrier.getValue()
 ) {
     return true;
 } else {
     return 'This valid is not valid.';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The final 'else' block in question has no execution path that will reach it.

You need to clarify which situation is encapsulated by that final 'else' condition, then rework your enclosing braces accordingly to ensure they reflect your intention.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple else blocks (since either the first if or first else block will always execute), combine them into one or nest them like this:

```
function validatePrivate(v){
    if (cbSwitchStatus.getValue()!='P') {
        if (v=='') return true;
        else return 'This valid is not valid.';
    }
    else if (storePrivate.findExact('disp',v) > -1){
        return true;
    }
    else if(cbServCarrier.getValue() != cbPrivateCarrier.getValue()) {
         return true;
    }
    else {
        return 'This value is not valid.'
    };
}
```